# binary search tree for finding more than one object

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I've just read about binary search trees from the "Learn You a Haskell" book, and I'm wondering whether it is effective to search more than one element using this tree? For example, suppose I have a bunch of objects where every object has some index, and

```
        5
      /   \
     3     7
    / \   / \
   1   4 6   8
```

if I need to find an element by index 8, I need to do only three steps `5 -> 7 -> 8`, instead of iterating over the whole list until the end. But what if I need to find several objects, say 1, 4, 6, 8? It seems like I'd need to repeat the same action for each element `5-> 3 -> 1` `5 -> 3 -> 4`, `5 -> 7 -> 6` and `5 -> 7 -> 8`.

So my question is: does it still make sense to use binary search tree for finding more than one element? Could it be better than checking each element for condition (which leads only to O(n) in the worst case)?

Also, what kind of data structure is better to use if I need to check more than one attribute. E.g. in the example above, I was looking only for the `id` attribute, but what if I also need to search by `name`, or `color`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share some of the work. See `members`, which takes in a list of values and outputs a list of exactly those values of the input list that are in the tree. Note: The order of the input list is not perserved in the output list.

EDIT: I'm actually not sure if you can get better performance  (from a theoretical standpoint) with `members` over doing `map member`. I *think* that if the input list is sorted, then you could by splitting the list in threes (lss, eqs, gts) could be done easily.

```
data BinTree a
  = Branch (BinTree a) a (BinTree a)
  | Leaf
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

empty :: BinTree a
empty = Leaf

singleton :: a -> BinTree a
singleton x = Branch Leaf x Leaf

add :: (Ord a) => a -> BinTree a -> BinTree a
add x Leaf = singleton x
add x tree@(Branch left y right) = case compare x y of
  EQ -> tree
  LT -> Branch (add x left) y right
  GT -> Branch left y (add x right)

member :: (Ord a) => a -> BinTree a -> Bool
member x Leaf = False
member x (Branch left y right) = case compare x y of
  EQ -> True
  LT -> member x left
  GT -> member x right

members :: (Ord a) => [a] -> BinTree a -> [a]
members xs Leaf = []
members xs (Branch left y right) = eqs ++ members lts left ++ members gts right
  where
    comps = map (\x -> (compare x y, x)) xs
    grab ordering = map snd . filter ((ordering ==) . fst)
    eqs = grab EQ comps
    lts = grab LT comps
    gts = grab GT comps
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your binary tree is balanced, if you have a constant number k of search items, then k searches with a total time of O(k * log(n)) is still better than a single O(n) search, where at each character, you still have to do k comparisons, making it O(k*n).  Even if the list of search items is sorted, and you can binary search in O(log(k)) time to see if your current item is a match, you're still at O(n * log(k)), which is worse than the tree unless k is Theta(n).

Comment: For your second question, there's not many good options available.  If you're doing n searches, then it might be beneficial to create a new tree in n*log(n) time, and then do n searches in log(n) time each, as opposed to n searches in n time on a regular list.  If you're only doing a single search at a time, then you're best off leaving it in its current format and settling for a worst case O(n) search.

Answer (score 1):

A quite acceptable solution when searching for multiple elements is to search for them one at a time with the most efficient algorithm (which is O(log n) in your case). However, it can be quite advantageous to step through the entire tree and pool all the elements that match a certain condition, it really depends on where and how often you search inside your code. If you only search at one point in your code it would make sense to collect all the elements in the tree in one shot instead of searching for them one by one. If you decide to opt for that solution then you could feasibly use other data structures such as a list.

If you need to check for multiple attributes I suggest replacing "id" with a tuple containing all the different possible identifiers (id, color, ...). You can then unpack the tuple and compare whichever identifiers you want.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A single search is O(log n).  4 searchs is (4 log n).  A linear search, which would pick up all items, is O(n).  The tree structure of a btree means finding more than one datum requires a walk (which is actually worse than a list walk).